# Taking information and putting another page using Data Validation in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript

I've been trying Google Apps Script a submit button using data validation ranges, however I'm struggling.

```
function submit2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var IBR = ss.getSheetByName('IBR');
  var lastColumn = IBR.getLastColumn()+1;
  var cell = IBR.getRange(7,5,7);
  var total = ss.getSheetByName('MS').getRange('G2:G13').getValue();
  cell.setValue(total);
}
```

Here's picture of data and below the validation, the submit image once click should reflect that date and take numbers and put them on a second page

[image: Here's the first page]

And there's where second page would receive the information

[image: And there's where second page would receive the information]

Comment: Here's my current code if that helps

Comment: function submit2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var IBR = ss.getSheetByName('IBR');
  var lastColumn = IBR.getLastColumn()+1;
  var cell = IBR.getRange(7,5,7);
  var total = ss.getSheetByName('MS').getRange('G2:G13').getValue();
  cell.setValue(total);
}

Comment: Done sorry, i'm new here.

Comment: Not sure how to imply the range within the code